# Combining PHP hosted on a web server and jQuery to submit a form using a POST function?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, function

I've created a PHP function which is hosted on a web server. The code here is designed to allow the user to create a user account which requires their forename, surname, email and password. I can use *Apigee* to submit the data, so I know that everything works. A snapshot of my code is below:

```
function student2_post() {
    $this->load->database();
    $StudentID = $_POST['StudentID'];
    $StudentForename = $_POST['StudentForename'];
    $StudentSurname = $_POST['StudentSurname'];
    $StudentEmail = $_POST['StudentEmail'];
    $StudentPassword = $_POST['StudentPassword'];
    $info = array('StudentID'=>null, 'StudentForename'=>$StudentForename, 'StudentSurname'=>$StudentSurname, 'StudentEmail'=>$StudentEmail, 'StudentPassword'=>$StudentPassword);
    $this->db->insert('StudentLogin', $info);
    $data->StudentID = $StudentID;
    $data->StudentForename = $StudentForename;
    $data->StudentSurname = $StudentSurname;
    $data->StudentEmail = $StudentEmail;
    $data->StudentPassword = $StudentPassword;
    $this->response($data, 200);
    }
```

My next step of development is to try and develop an "app" or a mobile service which allows me to use my own GUI. 
My code for this is below:

```
<!-- Home -->
<div id="page2" class="ui-bar-a" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="320CT_Coursework.min">
        <h3>
            320CT
        </h3>
    </div>


    <div data-role="content">


    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="StudentID">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <label for="StudentID">
                    Name
                </label>

                <input name="" id="StudentID" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
            </fieldset>
        </div>


        <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="StudentForename">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <label for="StudentForename">
                    Surname
                </label>
                <input name="" id="StudentForename" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
            </fieldset>
        </div>


        <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="StudentSurname">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <label for="StudentSurname">
                    Email
                </label>

                <input name="" id="StudentSurname" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
            </fieldset>
        </div>


        <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="StudentPassword">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <label for="StudentPassword">
                    Password
                </label>
                <input name="" id="StudentPassword" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
            </fieldset>
        </div>


        <input type="submit" value="Submit">


    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works and brings up a GUI for me to enter data in, however obviously it doesn't link up. I've got all the form elements there I need, with IDs which is kosher to the PHP function.

I've been unable to find any resources which allow me to use the PHP function ***student2_POST*** in my jQuery code. Everything I find seems to be related to non-PHP functions.

TLDR:
I have a function hosted on a web service which submits a form and I need a way to implement this function in jQuery. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In order to communicate between client (html / js) and server (php), you need to execute an HTTP request.

This may tipycally be done using an HTML `form`, or dynamically using AJAX methods such as (for JQuery) :

- [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)`( url [, settings ] )`

  > Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.
- [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)`( url \[, data \] \[, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) \] \[, dataType \] )`

  > Load data from the server using a HTTP POST request.

Comment: Thank you Geoffroy, I'm assuming that I'd have to use this example
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());

Question 1:
How would I give an ID to my form? Currently it's just on a page

Question 2: 
How would I then connect up the POST to the submit button?

Comment: @JonnyBird And ID to your form? What for ? And add a onclick listener on your button to call the `$.post` method :)

Comment: Well the example has "#testform" which I assumed was some sort of ID? And I'm completely lost with the onclick listener..the examples there don't seem to link up with a button, just with text??

Comment: I think you should study html first, it will be better for you. Sorry but I can't do everything for you. You should know at least a bare minimum about HTML / DOM / Javascript and events before using JQuery and making HTML web pages.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:
[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)